# Number of samples required to have visited all classes of a uniformly distributed distribution?

Tags: sampling, unbalanced-classes, uniform-distribution

So let's say I have a set of binary vectors $x \in \{0,1\}^n$. Hence, $|\{x\}| = 2^n$  . For all $x$, there is a class $c_i$. We do not know what is this class a priori, but we can compute it once we sample $x$.

There are polynomially many such classes and the number of such classes is bounded above by $n^{k}$ for some $k$ (known to us).

I also know that $|\{x_i: x_i \in c_i\}| \approx |\{x_j: x_j \in c_j\}| $ i.e there are equally many $x$'s in each class.

Now, my question, what is the fastest way to draw at-least one sample from each class. Is there anything better than uniform sampling ? And How can I device a good stopping criterion ? I only know the bound on the number of classes not the exact number of classes, can there be a $(\delta,\epsilon)$ guarantee on visiting all the classes ?

Comment: Within this question appear a strange mix of assumptions.  The question as formulated appears to be answerable for any given (but arbitrary) $n$ without any of the information it provides: what is the point of providing asymptotic information?  Also, by "fastest way to draw" what do you really mean? Objectively, one starts with a list of members of the classes and takes one member from each class: done. Are you supposing the sampling must be blind to class membership? If so, what possible alternatives to uniform sampling could there be? Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I see my question was poorly explained. We do not know the number of classes, and getting a sample from each class is precisely the goal. Also, It is much harder to the reverse process of generating a sample given the class. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you: I think the nature of your question is clear enough.  I wonder, though, what you might mean by "fastest way."  Isn't it necessary to sample uniformly and sequentially; and the only issue concerns when to stop sampling?  You just don't have any information you could possibly to exploit to improve over that.  And since you're not in an asymptotic situation--you have a set of vectors, pure and simple--of what use are any asymptotic bounds on the number of classes?

Comment: One way to ask this question is: Suppose we have samples $x_1,\ldots x_n$ from a uniform distribution of $c$ classes, and have observed $m$ classes so far. What is the maximum likelihood estimate of $c$? And if we use a stopping criterion of $$P[x_1,\ldots x_n|c=m+1]< \epsilon P[x_1,\ldots x_n|c=m]$$ how can we calculate the probabilities easily, and what is the distribution of stopping times under various assumptions for $c$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: E.g. if our first dozen observations include three A’s, three B’s, three C’s, two D’s and an E, then $c$ is most likely 5. But if our first dozen observations include eight A’s, and one each of B, C, D, E, then maybe it’s more likely that $c$ is larger.

Comment: @MattF. I use an intuitive version of this to stop sampling so far. I stop when I stop seeing new samples. I agree with your formulation.

Comment: @wuber since $k$ is known, when you have a very large $n$ then the stopping criterion is relatively simple. For example if $k=2$ , then for n =25 , you will not really need many samples(w.r.t 2^(25)) before you would have visited all the classes. The problem is in my case $k$ is quite large $\approx 100$. Well, I would be interested if something can be said even theoretically for a case when n^k << 2^n, like what number of samples gaurentee with a certain confidence having visited all classes

Comment: That's a slightly different question.  I don't think you need maximum likelihood here, and it might even get in the way of developing an efficient solution, because after you have done some sampling you will obtain a fairly accurate estimate of the average class size and from that you can accurately estimate the chance of not having sampled one or more classes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have $n$ observations, with $m$ classes so far, and we want to determine the total number $c$ of classes. With a maximum likelihood approach, the most likely scenario is that all the classes have been observed if
$$n> 1+(m+\frac12)\log(m)$$

The probability of observing exactly $m$ classes after the first $n$ observations is $$p(c)=\binom{c}{m}m^n/c^n$$
We maximize this probability by finding the $c$ for which $$\frac{p(c)}{p(c+1)} =\frac{c+1-m}{c+1}\cdot\frac{(c+1)^n}{c^n}=1$$
i.e.
$$\log\left(1-\frac{m}{c+1}\right)+n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{c}\right)=0$$

This occurs with $c=m$ iff
$$n = \frac{\log(m+1)}{\log(m+1)-\log(m)}$$
and approximating that gives the first inequality here.

To find the most likely $c$, we can solve the equation with logs numerically. It's hard to find a nice formula that's close to the root for a wide range of $m$ and $n$.

We can also use the formula for $p(c)/p(c+1)$ to test whether any other $c$ will be less likely by a factor of $\epsilon$.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply and sorry for late response, can you please explain me how you evaluate the probability of observing exactly $m$ classes? In my understanding this seems to be an over estimate

Comment: For example, Let us have 4 classes A, B,C,D. Now, in three trials the probability of picking exactly three classes is 4*(1/4)^3, but in your case it would be 4*(3/4)^3.

Comment: I guess the right expression should be  ${c \choose m}(m/c)^n - {c \choose (m-1)}((m-1)/c)^n $

Comment: @SagarM, I now think it's even worse than that, and needs an inclusion-exclusion principle: $\sum (-1)^{m-k} \binom{c}{k} k^n / c^n$, summing over $1 \le k \le m$.